# NSWindow property set with the assign attribute instead of the strong

Tags: macos

I notice the Mac App template has create the following:

> @interface AppDelegate : NSObject
>
> @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

According to the ARC guidelines all top level object should use a strong property but instead this is using an assign property.  Would someone explain why?

Comment: My guess is that it's a deficiency in the template. It wouldn't be the first! Don't trust code just because it's in the Apple template.

Answer (score 2):

A window will generally be "owned" by `File's Owner`, which will usually be your `NSApplication` instance (for the main nib) or an instance of `NSWindowController`, not necessarily the app delegate or the window delegate. This is why it wouldn't be appropriate for the reference to be strong inside the delegate class.

In Mac OS/X 10.7, `NSWindow` (along with several other Cocoa classes) didn't support management via ARC, so declared properties to `NSWindow` had to be `assign` rather than `strong` or `weak`. See the [Transitioning to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Nib Object Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) documents for a more detailed discussion. The basic answer is that you can't use ARC-managed references for objects that override the `release` and `retain` methods.

In 10.8, it looks like NSWindow isn't on that list, but Xcode is still generating the `assign` attribute rather than `weak`.

Comment: So it should be safe to change it to `weak` on 10.8 then?

Comment: If the apple tech docs (see Transitioning to ARC above) are accurate, then yes, it should be OK to change it to weak.